# Get all occurances of string pattern in variable using preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a variable, for example:

```
$str = 'a string1 ab string2 abc string3 abcd string4 abcde string1 abcdef string2';
```

I want to `use preg_match_all` to get all unique occurrences of `string(n)`.

My code so far is:

```
preg_match_all('%string([0-9])%', $str, $matches);
```

What I want is to return the `$matches` array that looks like:

```
Array (
[0] => 'string1'
[1] => 'string2'
[2] => 'string3'
[3] => 'string4'
)
```

But instead I get multiple nested arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax is fine, but the reason you are getting a nested array is because you have defined a capture group around the number in `string1`, `string2`, etc.  Remove that unwanted capture group, remove duplicates, and you will get the behavior you want here.

```php
$str = 'a string1 ab string2 abc string3 abcd string4 abcde string1 abcdef string2';
preg_match_all('/\bstring[0-9]+\b/', $str, $matches);
$strings = array_unique($matches[0]);
print_r($strings);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string1
    [1] => string2
    [2] => string3
    [3] => string4
)
```